# Add Commerce Checkout progress bar and extra stage

Tags: 7, commerce

I believe as such there is no template file for checkout? So how I want to add the following graphical navigation to the top of commerce checkout?

[image]

Can i target checkout with a page.tpl.php? Alternatively a hook in template.php?

At each stage/page of checkout the navigation images will change.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want the [Commerce Checkout Progress](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_progress) module.